# Excel 2013 time calculation

Tags: excel

my start date and time in 1 cell is -->

> 7/03/2016  16:54:00

now I want to add 18h

---

I only want to calculate the working hours:

> 8:30:00 until 17:30:00

---

Don't forget these hours/days shoudln't be calculated:

- weekends (saterdays and sundays)
- public holidays

what should the formula be in excel 2013 ?

Comment: one of the biggest problems you will face with that calculation is that every country has different public holidays,  heck some provinces, states, territories within the same country have different holidays.

Comment: I think you want to take a look at this link on [How to calculate net work hours using networkdays](http://www.exceltactics.com/calculate-net-work-hours-using-networkdays/)